# Fork/ execlp in #pragma omp parallel for stops arbitrarily

Tags: openmp

I am programming a Kalman-Filter based realtime program in C using a large number of realizations. To generate the realization output I have to execute an external program (groundwater simulation software) about 100 times. I am therefore using OpenMP with fork and exceclp for parallelization of this block:

```
  #pragma omp parallel for private(temp)

    for(i=1;i<=n_real;i++){

    /* Start ensemble model run */

    int = fork();
    int ffork = 0;
    int status;

    if (pid == 0) {
         //Child process
         log_info("Start Dadia for Ens %d on thread %d",i,omp_get_thread_num());
         sprintf(temp,"ens_%d",i);
         chdir(temp);
         execlp("../SPRING/dadia","dadia","-return","-replace_kenn","73","ini.csv","CSV",NULL);
         log_info("Could not execute function dadia - exit anyway");
         ffork = 1;
         _exit(1);
    }
    else{
         //Parent process
         wait(NULL);
         if (ffork == 0){
            log_info("DADIA run ens_%d successfully finished",i);
         }
    }
 }
```

In general the code runs smoothly for small number of realizations (with 6 threads). However sometimes the code hangs in the last cycle of parallel iterations. The occurrence only happens if number iterations >> number threads. I tried scheduling the for loop with different options, but it didn't solve the problem. I know that fork is not the best solution to use with OpenMP. But I am wondring why it's sometimes hangs at arbitrary points.

Thank's a lot for any kind if feedback.

Different Ubuntu versions tried (including difffrent comiler versions)

Comment: I do not think OpenMP runtimes support such a fork/join code safely. Why do you want to create new processes in a multithreaded loop like this in the first place? It should not be (significantly) faster. In fact, it should even be slower due to the overhead of the workers possibly using an active loop regarding the target OpenMP configuration/runtime. I expect the OS to use a big lock in that case. Additionally, multiple processes runs in parallel so there is no need for multiple threads to do that. Please consider using a basic sequential loop.

Comment: Your `ffork` is a local variable. You need to make it shared. And then you need to somehow synchronize the forking & waiting. It sounds to me like one thread could be waiting before the other one has forked. What is `_exit`? It sounds very dangerous.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the fast feedback. The reason I am using the fork construct is that to my knowledge a standard system command is starting a new process and eliminating the parallel process. As mentioned in other posts this can be avoided by using execlp and fork. In need to run the dadia function in parallel as it takes quite some time and I have to do it at least 100 times. The _exit is used to ensure that the child process is terminated even if the execlp does not finish correctly.

Comment: With your comments I tried again using the system command without the fork construct. It is running (with making use of all available threads) but somehow the dadia program is not saving the results for each iteration (even if running for each iteration).

Answer (score 0):

This version finally seems to run stable. Thank's for your hints:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(temp) schedule(dynamic)

for(i=1;i<=n_real;i++) {

    /* Start ensemble model run */

    /* Calling bash-commands inside OpenMP enviroment requires using fork().
       Else the parallel process is terminated.
       Note exec automatically ends the child process after termination.
       If Sitra fails, the child process needs to be terminated manually  */


    pid_t pid = 0;
    int   status;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        log_info("Start SITRA for Ens %d on thread %d",i,omp_get_thread_num());
        sprintf(temp,"ens_%d",i);
        chdir(temp);
        execl("../SPRING/sitra","sitra","-return",(char *) 0);
        perror("In exec(): ");
    }
    if (pid > 0) {
        pid = wait(&status);
        log_info("End of sitra for ensemble %d",i);
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("Sitra ended with exit(%d).\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("Sitra ended with kill -%d.\n", WTERMSIG(status));
        }
    }
    if (pid < 0){
        perror("In fork():");
    }
}
```